# How to monitor network activity in openwrt

Tags: network-monitoring, openwrt

I'm having what feels like slow internet from time to time, with ping to google.com at 3000ms and up or even timeouts, and I'd like to check if the problem comes from the ISP or if it's from my network (there are several computers and devices that may be updating softwares/apps, users checking youtube videos, ...).

Can I install something on my OpenWRT router to monitor what's happening and try to pinpoint who the culprit is?

If found https://github.com/pyrovski/wrtbwmon which could tell me which computers/devices are eating the bandwidth, but it may not be that useful if the issue is on the ISP's end.

Answer (score 2):

High latency is sometimes due to contention for upstream bandwidth. wrtbwmon would certainly help you figure out which device is using bandwidth, but it is designed for long-term monitoring. If you want a real-time solution, try iftop.